# How to join another table with the same table but different condition

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I want to display a school where a student graduated from. I have a table of school name and a table of student profile. Here's my code:

**school_db**

```
shc_id       shc_title
1            School A
2            School B
3            School C
4            School D
5            School E
```

**student_db**

```
stu_id       stu_school1         stu_school2           stu_school3
1                 1                   2                     2
2                 1                   2                     4
3                 2                   2                     4
```

So I write:

```
select school_db.sch_title as school from school_db
inner join student_db on student_db.stu_school1=school_db.shc_id
inner join student_db on student_db.stu_school2=school_db.shc_id
inner join student_db on student_db.stu_school3=school_db.shc_id
where student_db.stu_id='1'
```

But I failed to get the correct result. So could you please suggest how to use a proper join in this case.

I expect the result to be like:

```
stu_id        stu_school1         stu_school2           stu_school3
1             School A            School B              School B
2             School A            School B              School D
3             School B            School B              School D
```

Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be joining table `school_db` thrice on table `student_db` so that you can get the values for each column on table `student_db`.

One more thing, you should unique define alias on table `school_db` so the server can identify to which the tables and columns has been joined.

```
SELECT  a.stu_id,
        b.shc_title sc1,
        c.shc_title sc2,
        d.shc_title sc3
FROM    student_db a
        INNER JOIN school_db b
            ON a.stu_school1 = b.shc_id
        INNER JOIN school_db c
            ON a.stu_school2 = c.shc_id
        INNER JOIN school_db d
            ON a.stu_school3 = d.shc_id
WHERE   a.stu_id = '1'
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/980f6/5)

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Comment: @Wilf one more thing, if the of of the columns of schoolID on table `student_db`, better use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` so that even the student will show on the result list even if it has no matching school on `school_db`.

Answer (score 2):

Each of the re-joins must have a unique alias:

```
INNER JOIN student_db AS db1 ON school_db.shc_id = db1.stu_school1
                      ^^^^^^                       ^^^
INNER JOIN student_db AS db2 etc...
```

As for your results, what you want is known as a pivot query, which MySQL doesn't support directly. There's workarounds, but they're very ugly and hard to maintain. You'd be better off performing a regular query, then doing the table formatting in your client.

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake is to join 3 times with the table student with one school table, while your problem is about one student having 3 schools:

```
SELECT 
    student_db.stu_id, 
    s1.sch_title as school1, 
    s2.sch_title as school2, 
    s3.sch_title as school3
FROM 
    student_db
        INNER JOIN school_db s1 ON student_db.stu_school1=s1.shc_id
        INNER JOIN school_db s2 ON student_db.stu_school2=s2.shc_id
        INNER JOIN school_db s3 ON student_db.stu_school3=s3.shc_id
WHERE student_db.stu_id='1'
```

But when there's not always 3 schools, you should show:

```
SELECT 
    student_db.stu_id, 
    s1.sch_title as school1, 
    IFNULL(s2.sch_title, 'No school selected') as school2, 
    IFNULL(s3.sch_title, 'No school selected') as school3
FROM 
    student_db
        INNER JOIN school_db s1 ON student_db.stu_school1=s1.shc_id
        LEFT JOIN school_db s2 ON student_db.stu_school2=s2.shc_id
        LEFT JOIN school_db s3 ON student_db.stu_school3=s3.shc_id
WHERE student_db.stu_id='1'
```